# header('location:index.php') redirects me to index.php after refreshing the page for 2 times

Tags: php, session, redirect, header, unset

I have a php page (index.php) in which after verifying the username and password a session will be set($_SESSION['expire']) that will be expired and unset after 30 mins (30 mins after pressing the login button) and will redirect us to index.php again:

```
header('location:index.php');
```

After verifying, a menu will be shown in index page that one of its item is ContentManager.php.
As shown below by clicking this item we will connected to the db and will enter contentmanager.php

```
switch($_REQUEST['action'])
{
case 'ContentManager' : 
include('model/content.php');
$contents = getContent($conn);
include('view/contentmanager.php');
break;
}
```

in the ContentManger.php I have:

```
<?php
//if the session is not unset and expired yet
    if ( isset($_SESSION['expire']) && ($now<= $_SESSION['expire']))
{   
?>
do sth...

<?php
}
else
{
//unset the session and redirect to index.php again
unset($_SESSION['expire']);
session_destroy(); 
header('location:../index.php');}
?>
```

This works fine, but the problem is that after passing 30 mintues  I have to press "ContentManager" 2 times to redirect to index.php
If I just press it one time a blank page with be shown. But by refreshing the page for second time it will redirect to login page (index.php) again.

Please help me...

Comment: `exit;` after `header(...)`

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work

Comment: And what is `expire` set to? Wouldn't this very check you wrote explain the 30 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

check your spacing before header include .it may cause error while redirecting.and another solution is check your **output buffering** 
is you output buffering set to **off or on**. 
To check this got to your servers php.ini file and check **output buffering** .If its off then set it on 
and if you don't have excess to edit php.ini file you may also on this typing the following code
`<?php ob_start();?>`
you must write this code for each page 
and to off **output buffering** 
type `<?php  ob_end_flush();?>`

Answer (score 0):

Its because youre outputting text (probably a blank line) before the header. In the example you posted it will output a the blank line between the ?> and the

Comment: I removed all the blank lines but it didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will resolve:

```
<?php
//if the session is not unset and expired yet
    if ( isset($_SESSION['expire']) && ($now<= $_SESSION['expire'])):
?>
do sth...

<?php
else {
//unset the session and redirect to index.php again
unset($_SESSION['expire']);
session_destroy(); 
header('location:../index.php');}

endif
?>
```